Query has exceeded resources
PowerBI:
I have a table containing store name and its capacity to hold goods of each category and another table containing item data like below, please note that capacity is at category level:


I want to create a table containing the possible SKUs combination for all stores within a category based on their capacity, SKU preference is based on code, i.e. SKU code 1 will be preferred than SKU Code 2 if capacity is only 1 for that category.

The report will have filters and the user can remove specific SKUs basis their need, in such a case that SKU will be removed from combination and next SKU will be preferred.
Please note that the dynamic SKU filtering out is crucial, hence ALLSELECTED is used while calculating dynamic RANK. Please help if their is any other approach which can be used or if the existing approach can be optimized for use.
I have created below DAX queries which is giving correct result and working well for dynamic filters:
CATEGORY_CAPACITY =
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE(STORE[CAPACITY]),
    STORE[CATEGORY] = SELECTEDVALUE(SKU[CATEGORY])
)
 

DYNAMIC_SKU_RANK =
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(SKU),
        SKU[CATEGORY] = MAX(SKU[CATEGORY])
    ),
    CALCULATE(MIN(SKU[SKU_ORDERED])),
    ,
    ASC
)
 

APPLICABLE_SKU =
IF(
    [DYNAMIC_SKU_RANK] <= [SUB_CATEGORY_CAPACITY],
    1,
    0
)

In my output table, I am only showing APPLICABLE_SKU = 1.
When use this approach on my actual data, I am receiving "Query exceeded resources error".
